# Ansible how to store output of register in list when iterated over inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am running a shell command, this command runs for all hosts listed in my inventory file. I am then using register to define the variable, when i retrieve these values for debug messages i see register variable for all hosts printed for all IP in my inventory but i want to store them in a list so that i can use them in templates. How can we achieve it?

```html
- name: Command
    shell: hostname -f
    register: fqdn_name
```

Comment: paste your register result as well so we'll help you

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, you are doing more work than you need to. Each time Ansible runs against a host, it collects a series of 'facts' about the host and stores them in a dictionary available during your plays. Therefore, replace your existing Command task with the following, to see what I mean:

```
- name: Display the Ansible FQDN fact
  debug:
    var: ansible_fqdn
```

Running `ansible -m setup <hostname taken from inventory file>` will show you all the variables that get collected.

The variables for all your hosts are made available through a special dictionary called 'hostvars', therefore in your template you can do something like this:

```
{% for host in groups.all %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_fqdn'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could replace `groups.all` with `groups.<some inventory groupname>` to limit the matched hosts to a particular group.

One possible gotcha here, is that these facts will only have been collected if Ansible has already targeted a host, therefore one strategy for more complex playbooks is:

```
# This play simply connects to all your hosts and gathers facts
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

# Now all subsequent plays have access to facts for all hosts
- hosts: <all or some group>
  tasks: ...
```